# Windows8 App FileOpenPicker - Setting the Position and Size

Tags: windows-8

Developing a windows 8 application in which i am using FileOpenPicker.

```
      FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();

      picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
      picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
      picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
      picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
      picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
      picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".tiff");
      picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");
```

Is there a way to adjust the location and size of the FileOpenPicker? I do not want the FileOpenPicker to occupy the complete screen. I did not see any options in FileOpenPicker class.
I do not want to go with the option of developing a custom file picker since I would have to then do all the functionality of FileOpenPicker (like integrating with File Picker contracts) etc.

Please provide input whether it is feasible.

Comment: This is just my experience, but when I've used Windows Store apps they, and their file selection dialogs, have always occupied the entire screen.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: nope... in fact you need to make sure it's not invoked when you're in snapped mode either see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/ddaae084-df74-4ed4-b331-975164f496ee)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Windows Store apps are designed so they could be immersive and display only relevant content on the screen. So, they are always full screen, except when you snap them.